# Python: fast iteration through file

Tags: python, iteration

I need to iterate through two files many million times,
counting the number of appearances of word pairs throughout the files.
(in order to build contingency table of two words to calculate Fisher's Exact Test score)

I'm currently using

```
from itertools import izip
src=tuple(open('src.txt','r'))
tgt=tuple(open('tgt.txt','r'))
w1count=0
w2count=0
w1='someword'
w2='anotherword'
for x,y in izip(src,tgt):
    if w1 in x:
         w1count+=1
    if w2 in y:
         w2count+=1
    .....
```

While this is not bad, I want to know if there is any faster way to iterate through two files, hopefully significantly faster.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: You will need to provide more information. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @InbarRose I added more information. Please let me know if it still doesn't suffice :)

Comment: Well, there is still much information missing. Any variable that you use in any code that you display here, you should show the declaration, for instance: what is `src`, `tgt`, `w1`, `w2`, `w1count`, and `w2count`?

Comment: What do you mean by counting "word pairs"?  Do your files have the same number of lines?

Comment: @SvenMarnach yes they do

Comment: Maybe you can give an example of a short example input/output.

Comment: @SvenMarnach the n-th line in tgt file is a conversational response to n-th line in src file. So I'd like to count the number of appearances of two words, and their co-appearnaces in the same lines, in order to calculate fishers exact score.

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc Do you only need to count them when both words are on the same line, or also when one word appears individually? Also, do you have multiple word pairs?

Comment: @poke I count both words on the same line, and also each word's separate counts. I have many millions of words pairs to count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't quite get what exactly you are trying to do, but here's some example code that might point you in the right direction.

We can use a dictionary or a `collections.Counter` instance to count all occurring words and pairs *in a single pass* through the files.  After that, we only need to query the in-memory data.

```
import collections
import itertools
import re

def find_words(line):
    for match in re.finditer("\w+", line):
        yield match.group().lower()

counts1 = collections.Counter()
counts2 = collections.Counter()
counts_pairs = collections.Counter()

with open("src.txt") as f1, open("tgt.txt") as f2:
    for line1, line2 in itertools.izip(f1, f2):
        words1 = list(find_words(line1))
        words2 = list(find_words(line2))
        counts1.update(words1)
        counts2.update(words2)
        counts_pairs.update(itertools.product(words1, words2))

print counts1["someword"]
print counts1["anotherword"]
print counts_pairs["someword", "anotherword"]
```

Comment: sorry just one more question. After running this program, how do I retrieve each word's or word pair's count?

Comment: I tried counts1.most_common() but it returns ('<_sre.sre_match object at 0x10c7325e0>', 17) which is why I get 0 for counts1['you']... is there a way to handle this?

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc: I fixed `find_words()` and added examples on how to get some counts.

Answer (score 0):

In general if your data is small enough to fit into memory then your best bet is to:

1. Pre-process data into memory
2. Iterate from memory structures

If the files are large you may be able to pre-process into data structures, such as your zipped data, and save into a format such as pickle that is much faster to load & work with in a separate file then process that.

Comment: my files are 37MB and 36MB each. Is it small enough to fit into memory?

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc: Almost certainly.  But I think changing your algorithm would be the right approach.

Comment: @SvenMarnach thanx. any advice as to how to change the algorithm?

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc: I can only answer that if you specify what you mena by "counting word pairs".  It's completely unclear to me from both your code and your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an out of the box thinking solution: 
Have you tried making the files into Pandas data frames?  I.e. I assume you already you make a word list out of the input (by removing reading signs such as . and ,) and using a input.split(' ') or something similar. That you can then make into DataFrames, perform a wordd count and then make a cartesian join?

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(src, columns=['word_1'])
df_1['count_1'] = 1
df_1 = df_1.groupby(['word_1']).sum()
df_1 = df_1.reset_index()

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(trg, columns=['word_2'])
df_2['count_2'] = 1
df_2 = df_2.groupby(['word_2']).sum()
df_2 = df_2.reset_index()

df_1['link'] = 1
df_2['link'] = 1

result_df = pd.merge(left=df_1, right=df_2, left_on='link', right_on='link')
del result_df['link']
```

I use stuff like this for basket analysis, works really well.